# How to build ripple client on local?

Tags: ripple

I'm trying to build [ripple-client](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-client) on my computer following it's README.md and wiki.

But, after I run `grunt devserver` and access `http://local.ripple.com`, log in into my account. I can only find nothing but a navbar.

In my developer tools, I see a lot of errors, but nobody refer such situation on github issues or their bug tracker so I'm not sure if something I have done was wrong. `send` and `trade` page looked like this also.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7qNa.png

If these steps wrong or it's a bug?

1. `` git clone https://github.com/ripple/ripple-client`
   npm install
   bower install ``
2. Modify ripple.txt and config.js for using production server ( staging seems doesn't work).
3. `grunt` and `grunt devserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/ripple/ripple-client`
npm install
bower install
cp src/js/config{-example,}.js
grunt
grunt devserver
```

You don't have to modify ripple.txt since you can login by appending @rippletrade.com to your Ripple ID, like ~orzfly@rippletrade.com.

About the errors appeared in your console, you can find it on the production rippletrade.com too :(.

BTW, you should have a look at the first lines in your console instead of these SVG related messages.

Comment: first line is ` Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="NaN"`
and the problem is the `trade`, `send` page dosen't show anything.